# Signaling mechanism for one thread waiting on several

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm designing a system where a pool of workers pop jobs out of a queue, and I want the main thread to wait for all that to be done. This is what I've come up with so far (pseudocode):

```
// Main
launch_signal();
for (auto &worker : pool) {
    // create unique_lock
    if (!worker.done)
        worker.condition_variable.wait(lock, worker.done);
}

// Worker
if (queue.empty()) {
    mutex.lock();
    this->done = true;
    mutex.unlock();
    this->condition_variable.notify_one();
    // wait for launch signal from Main
} else {
    mutex.lock();
    auto job = queue.pop();
    mutex.unlock();
    job.execute();
}
```

So `Main` signals that jobs are available, then waits for every worker to signal back. `Worker` meanwhile keeps popping jobs off the queue until empty, then signals done and goes into waiting for launch signal.

My question: What is a more efficient algorithm for doing this?

Comment: [OT] You should really use a [`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) instead of manually locking and unlocking the mutex.

Comment: Absolutely, such (important) details omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existing code appears to access `queue.empty()` without holding a mutex lock. Unless the `queue` object itself is thread-safe, (or at least the `queue.empty()` method is explicitly documented as being thread-safe), this will be undefined behavior.

So the first improvement would be to fix this likely bug.

Otherwise, this is a fairly stock, battle-tested, implementation of a worker pool. There's not much room for improvement here.

The only suggestion I can make is that if the number of worker threads is `N`, and after locking the mutex a thread finds that there are `J` jobs in the queue, the thread could remove `J/N` jobs (with the result of the division being at least 1) from the queue at once, and then do them in the sequence, on the assumptions that all other threads will do the same, and jobs take about the same amount of time to be done, on average. This will minimize lock contention.